# OpenNLP: Unable to locate the model file for Lemmatizer

Tags: opennlp, lemmatization

**Summary**: Unable to find the model file used for Lemmatizer (english-lemmatizer.bin)

**Details**: [OpenNLP Tools Models](http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/models-1.5/) appears to be a comprehensive repository for the various models used by the different components of the Apache OpenNLP library.  However, I am unable to find the model file *en-lemmatizer.bin*, which is used with the lemmatizer.  The Apache OpenNLP Developer Manual provides the following code snippet for the Lemmatization step:

```
InputStream dictLemmatizer = null;

try (dictLemmatizer = new FileInputStream("english-lemmatizer.bin")) {

}
```

However, unlike other model files, I am just not able to find the location of this model file.  Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The book "Natural Language Processing with Java Cookbook' by Richard M. Reese provides a good answer.  For some reason en-lemmatizer.bin is not available for direct download from the web, but it can be created using the following steps:

1. Download and untar `apache-opennlp-1.9.0-bin.tar` (https://opennlp.apache.org/download.html)
2. Go to the URL for the [Lemmatizer Training File](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-opennlp-auto-tagging/master/src/main/resources/models/en-lemmatizer.dict) and save the text content as *en-lemmatizer.dict*
3. Go to the bin directory (from step 1, after untarring) and
   execute the following command:

`opennlp LemmatizerTrainerME -model en-lemmatizer.bin -lang en -data /path/to/en-lemmatizer.dict -encoding UTF-8`

---

Note: Be prepared to handle the following error:

`Computing event counts...  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`

Answer (score 0):

You want en-lemmatizer.bin and not english-lemmatizer.txt