# OpenNLP: Unable to access jarfile LemmatizerTrainerME

Tags: java, maven, opennlp, lemmatization

I'm having trouble to build my Lemmatizer bin file.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57911951/14100521),
I should run `opennlp LemmatizerTrainerME -model en-lemmatizer.bin -lang en -data /path/to/en-lemmatizer.dict -encoding UTF-8` but it gives me an error: **Unable to access jarfile LemmatizerTrainerME**

I'm doing it inside apachenlp bin folder `(.\apache-opennlp-1.9.3\bin)`

Can someone help me fixing this or tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution. The `LemmatizerTrainerME` is inside opennlp tools jar file. So that's what I did:

I ran Windows Powershell inside **lib** folder with the following command: `opennlp opennlp-tools-1.9.3.jar LemmatizerTrainerME -model en-lemmatizer.bin -lang en -data /path/to/en-lemmatizer.dict -encoding UTF-8` and it worked.

TLDR: I ran Powershell inside the folder that contains opennlp tools and added the tools file name before the arguments so it could access LemmatizerTrainerME